# Combine two variables to call another variable Python

Tags: python

So I have this program that creates variables automatically depending on the number that the user inputted, but I need a way to call the variables again to retrieve the value from them.

This is what I have:

```
count = int(input("

for x in range(0, ):
                globals()['wordNumber%s' % x] = input("Word: ")
number = 1
while True:
    print (wordNumber.str(number))
    number = number + 1
```

For the `print` part, it tries to print just `wordNumber` which doesn't exist, so there is an error. I need it to somehow add `wordNumber` together with a number (1-5) so it can `print(wordNumber1)` or `print(wordNumber3)`

Comment: Why not just use an array?

Answer (score 2):

Use a normal dict to store the data:

```
nums = {}
count = int(input("Enter range: "))
for x in range(0, count):
    nums['wordNumber%s' % x] = input("Word: ")
print(nums)
```

Demo:

```
Enter range: 2
Word: foo
Word: bar

In [5]: nums
Out[5]: {'wordNumber0': 'foo', 'wordNumber1': 'bar'}
In [6]: nums["wordNumber0"]
Out[6]: 'foo'
In [7]: nums["wordNumber1"]
Out[7]: 'bar'
```